# Abstain from exercise the day after a "drinking night"?

Tags: alcohol

I consider it common sense to avoid exercise after a night of two beers ([Kingfisher Strong](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kingfisher_%28beer%29)s in 650ml containers with 8% alcohol content). The day after drinking, I feel weaker and stiffer and get cramps for days if I do my **usual** effort in exercise.

But is "day after" exercise a bad idea **no matter** the quantity of alcohol consumed? Yesterday I had 500ml of the same stuff and I felt it best to not exercise today. What is the recommended way of regaining my pace after drinking?

Comment: what is this exercise you're doing, that is messed up for days after a couple beers?  have you tried just drinking more water, with and after your alcohol?  dehydration is the main cause of moderate hangovers.

Answer (score 5):

I personally NEED to exercise the day after. I feel like it helps to clean out my body and makes me feel refreshed afterwards. And when I drink it's at least 4-5 drinks, maybe beer, hard alcohol, wine, etc.

Seems like you cramp up due to dehydration, which is cause by drinking. Try drinking water with/after the alcohol, then have plenty in the morning before working out. Maybe a banana with and sea salt too for potassium + sodium (both are supposed to help with cramps).

Of course everyone is different, so your body might just not be able to take it. But I would say try some things out and see how you feel. Maybe also take a pre workout supplement like Muscle Pharm Assault before hand to give you some extra energy/pump.

Comment: My own personal experience is much the same. I've never had any adverse effects from gym sessions after drinking, even when I've had considerably more than the amount in the OP, and neither has anybody I train with as far as I'm aware. Yes, everybody is different, but if you're being affected for days because you exercised after drinking, there's probably something other than just the workout to blame.

Answer (score 3):

From [*Training With a Hangover*](http://startingstrength.com/index.php/site/hangover_starr), by Bill Starr:

> I made it a point to push them to personal records on several of the exercises in the program for that day. I wanted to show them that they did have control over their bodies, even when they wanted to throw up or just go lie down on the sit-up boards.

But, he also says it's not a good idea to make a habit of this:

> [I]t takes a toll on the nervous system to have to go through such an ordeal, and it was harder for the nervous system to recover than the muscular system.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest if you have the feeling it is not a good idea to exercise because of the way your body feels then it is indeed a good idea, skip that workout. However don't make it an excuse for not exercising. It also depends on when you workout. For eg : If you workout in the evening and you had a drink last evening, it shouldn't matter at all.